# Gitlab code analysis for ruby

Tags: ruby, gitlab

Is there a plugins for integrating code analysis gems for the ruby repositories hosted on gitlab?

Something like ruby-lint

Comment: run your code on ci and use the tools there. gitlab is not a proper place to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a couple of options here, one is to set up [gitlab-ci](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-ci) or another Continuous integration server (like [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/)) and sort it out that way, another way would be to add a [git pre-commit hook](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) and ensure that it's run before you commit locally, for an example [check here].(https://gist.github.com/mpeteuil/6147292)